# Type error: Too few arguments to function on query

Tags: laravel

I want to get the participants associated with a registration. But with code below it appears "Type error: Too few arguments to function".

Do you know why?

```
$rDetails = Registration::with([
    'participants' => function ($query, $registrationID) {
        $query->select('id', 'ticket_type_id')->where('registration_id', $registrationID);
    }
])->find($registrationID);

dd($rDetails);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is result of **function ($query, $registrationID).** In function() you can pass only one parameter. Corrected way is

```
$rDetails = Registration::with([
    'participants' => function ($query) use ($registrationID) {
        $query->select('id', 'ticket_type_id')->where('registration_id', $registrationID);
    }
])->find($registrationID);

dd($rDetails);
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears that there is no items "#relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#106 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]". Do you know why?

Comment: you must be select foreign keys also

Comment: check also in db has record or not??

Comment: Yes, it has. With: $rDetails = Registration::with([
    'participants' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('registration_id', 'ticket_type_id');
    }
])->find($registrationID); shows "#relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#289 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#291 ▶}
        1 => Participant {#293 ▶}
      ]
    }" but like that the query dont seems correct.

Comment: This is because in your db no record correspond 'registration_id'  ==  $registrationID in this condition

Comment: But do you know why it shows 2 participants with "$rDetails = Registration::with([ 'participants' => function ($query) { $query->select('registration_id', 'ticket_type_id'); } ])->find($registrationID);"?

Comment: add record correspond your condition  and try again

Comment: That means there in has 2 records of participants where participants.id == registration.participant_id

Comment: In the participants table there are 2 records where registration_id = 2. The "dd($registrationID);" shows "2".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172764/discussion-between-davit-and-jow).